# SQL Server 2008 - Querying Spatial Data

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server database that I have migrated to SQL Server 2008. I want to take advantage of the spatial features. However my data is using more traditional data types. For instance, I have the following two tables:

```
Location
--------
ID char(36)
Address nvarchar (256)
City nvarchar (256)
State char (2)
PostalCode char (10)

Order
-----
LocationID char(36)
Product nvarchar(30)
Quantity int
TotalPrice decimal
```

How can I use the spatial features of SQL Server 2008 to get the orders within a 10 mile radius of a particular postal code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to store the latitude and longitude in your `Location` table, and you will also need to have the latitude and longitude of your postcodes.

SQL Server can only work with coordinates. You may want to use a [reverse geocoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_geocoding) service to get the coordinates of your locations.

In any case, this is how your geospatial query could look like in SQL Server 2008:

```
DECLARE @some_point geography;
SET @some_point = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(-122.34900 47.65100)', 4326);

SELECT
    Order.Product
FROM
    Order
INNER JOIN
    Location ON (Location.ID = Order.LocationID)
WHERE
    Location.Position.STDistance(@some_point) < 16093;
```

The above assumes that your `Location` table would have a field of type [geography](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933917.aspx) called `Position`.